# Stop wordpress custom post type from appearing in search engines

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've create a new post type called "Company" for my current project.
Now issues is that, Google started indexing my company page like:
www.domain.com/company-name

I want to keep this area secret and not to be listed by any search engine.
I've come across this "publicly_queryable" arg. for register_post_type function. But I'm not sure that this will work the way I want.

I do not want to use any plugin for this.

Answer (score 5):

On that page, you could include the meta tag which tells robots not to index the page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Alternatively, you can make a `robots.txt` file at the base of your domain which tells them also not to index said page (crawlers are supposed to look for this file):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /company-name
```

Comment: I've not created a single post view file for this seprately. I know I can add a condition to header.php file for such post type. But is there any other way to do it from the functions.php. I don need single post view for this custom post type.

Comment: robots.txt is probably the easiest route for accomplishing what you need

Comment: Also there are going to be many entries, so is there way that the robot.txt is updated automatically whenever a new company is added.

Comment: I've same problem with the plugin i created in past. Is there a way to do any of this directly from plugin?

Comment: robots.txt will allow you to desginate folders, so i.e. `Disallow /companies/` would prevent search engines from also in turn crawling `/companies/company-name-here` - not sure if that helps you. Alternatively there are ways I can think of making a custom plugin to only inject the header on the specific pages you don't want crawled but I do not have the time to have an in depth discussion about it :/ I wish you luck!

Comment: @Jimmy - Suggested answer is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with a function you could add the noindex-tag by adding something like this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function noindex_for_companies()
{
    if ( is_singular( 'company' ) ) {
        return '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'noindex_for_companies');
```

*Replace `company` with your custom post type when it is different.*

Note that dis does not hide the post when somebody has the URL, it just encourages search engines to not index it.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in a similar situation. Thank you!

Comment: Is this answer really working? I tried but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is on the right track, but the function should echo not return:

```
function noindex_for_companies()
{
    if ( is_singular( 'company' ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'noindex_for_companies');
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach could be to use the `wp_robots()` filter, as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_robots/).

```
add_filter( 'wp_robots', function( $robots ) {
  if ( is_singular( 'company' ) ) {
    $robots['noindex']  = true;
    $robots['nofollow'] = true;
  }

  return $robots;
} );
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me.

To apply to multiple CPTs: `is_singular( array( 'type1', 'type2' ) )`